# click a button to save the input fields in a csv file in Tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I am creating a simple GUI interface with the hope of saving the input data in a csv file with Tkinker. I am done with the interface but I have challenges with the submit button to save the data. I want help so when I click the submit button, it saves the data in a csv file. Here are my codes

```
from tkinter import *
import csv
import os

window = Tk()

window.title("BUSINESS REGISTRATION ")

window.geometry('500x450')

# Field name
bNo = Label(window, text="BusinessNo :")
bName = Label(window, text="BusinessName :")

# Packing fileds to show on the GUI
bNo.grid(row=1, column=2)
bName.grid(row=2, column=2)

# Varibales for storing data
businessNo = StringVar
businessName = StringVar

# Creating entry fields
entry1 = Entry(window, textvariable=businessNo)
entry2 = Entry(window, textvariable=businessName)

# Packing entry fields
entry1.grid(row=1, column=3)
entry2.grid(row=2, column=3)

# creating csv file
file_exists = os.path.exists('BUSINESS REGISTRATION.csv')

with open('BUSINESS REGISTRATION.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
if file_exists:

    writer.writerow(businessNo)
else:
    writer.writerow(businessName)
    writer.writerow(businessNo)


# submit function
def callback():
mylabel = Label(window, )
mylabel.grid()


# Creating a submit button
submit_Button = Button(window, text="Submit", command=callback)
submit_Button.grid(row=3, column=3)

# creating a csv file


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: First of all, you have an indentation problems and so your posted code will not even run.  The code for creating the CSV file should be *inside* a function that gets invoked in response to a button click. Right now you do not have your code within such a function. Besides that, you have not described the actual problem you are having.

Comment: Edit your code with proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

u can use pandas then convert your data to DatFrame type then save it as csv or any other extention

```
import pandas as pd  #install pandas in your pc 

def save_to_csv(data):  
   data_to_save={'name':data[0],'age':data[1]}  
   df=pd.DataFrame(data_to_save)
   df.to_csv('your path/data.csv')

data=[('messi','ronaldo','neymar'),(34,35,30)]  #this exemple of data has name and age u can put any thing 
save_to_csv(data) # i call the function
```